# Is there a second solution to points and perpendicular bisectors problem?

Tags: geometry

There is a problem from M.Gardner book *("Wheels, Life, and other Mathematical Amusements", p. 201)*:

> [Hallard T. Croft] asked if there existed a finite set of points on the plane such that the perpendicular bisector of the line segment joining any two points would always pass through at least two other points of the set.

The known solution to this problem is:

> You need 8 points. Take 4 points (A, B, C, D), put them in the corners of a square with side 1 (ABCD). Add 4 more points (E, F, G, H) outside of the square, each corresponds to one side of the square and creates an equilateral triangle with this side (ABE, BCF, CDG, DAH).

I wonder whether there is any other solution to this problem (with at least 2 points in the set)?

Comment: What is Gardner's question exactly ? You set some hypotheses but you didn't ask any question.

Comment: @G.T.R, Gardner's question? Gardner had a problem to solve, not question. I have a question about this problem. And sorry, I do not have english version of the book to cite it preciselly.

Comment: Well, there is an obvious solution for any number of points divisible by $8$.

Comment: I think I may have been wrong about my comment FYI

Comment: @kaine, why? I do not see mistakes in 16 points solution..

Comment: Merely I had difficulty generalizing for any number divisible by 8.

Comment: @kaine, oh, indeed... Any 2 points must satisfy the requirement.. I am stupid.

Comment: Doensn't the perpendicular bisector of AE only pass through one point? (BF, CG, DH respectively)

Comment: @Grantwalzer Nope, it passes through B and F, given the symmetry of the construction it should be pretty obvious that AE and BF are perpendicular, and therefore when the perpendicular bisector pass through one of B and F it must also pass through the other. Similarly the other "odd" construction AF is obviously perpendicular to BG, and B is obviously equally far from A and F.

Comment: This was bugging me until I saw a picture: http://librarum.org/book/1569/214 Now it makes perfect sense. (In my head, I was doing isosceles triangles which screws everything up)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple degenerate cases: N=0 and N=1.  In those cases, there are zero pairs of points where the perpendicular bisector of the segment between them doesn't pass through at least two other points.

The problem also degenerates if we allow coincident points.

Comment: this is not what i am looking for, of course.